# std::istream::read does not block?

Tags: c++

In short, when I pipe data less than it needs, it doesn't wait. Source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  char buf[1024];
  cin.read(buf, 5);
  buf[5]='\0';
  cout<<buf<<endl;
}
```

g++ foo.cpp
  echo "123"  |  ./a.out

> 123

If I run `./a.out` directly, the program will wait till I input 5 characters.

Comment: Press Ctrl+D and program will not wait for more characters.

Comment: By the way, instead of using `echo`, you can simply do `./a.out <<< 123`.

Comment: You should check value returned by `cin.read` (i.e. sate of stream), and you should nod expect waiting

Comment: I want to why the program doesn't wait in the 1st case, `echo ...` and I want it to wait.@Revolver_Ocelot

Comment: [cin.read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) returns `cin`

Comment: Read carefully http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ at the place "If the input sequence runs out of characters to extract (i.e., the end-of-file is reached) before n characters have been successfully read, the array pointed to by s contains all the characters read until that point, and both the eofbit and failbit flags are set for the stream."

Answer (score 3):

`read` reads characters, until it read specified amount of characters or end of stream is encountered.

- When you pipe your data, system knows when stream ends and sends *end
  of stream* signal accordingly.
- When you send your data through interactive device, system does not
  know if you sent all data you want, or you want to enter more, so it
  asks you, waiting for input. You can send *end of stream* signal
  manually by pressing Ctrl+D on Linux to specify that there will not
  be any further input.

If you can use `stream.fail()` to check if last operation failed (didn't read all requested characters) and `stream.gcount()` to check how many characters were actually read.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code to the following

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  char buf[1024];
  do{
    cin.read(buf, 5);
    buf[5]='\0'; // can be moved out of loop (placed after while)
  }while(cin.gcount() < 5);
  cout<< "Result is >" << buf << "<" <<endl;
}
```

Now program is waiting until at least 5 characters were read to `buf`, but you should understand that `\n` is also character that is in `cin` stream because Enter is pressed by user

Comment: I must note that if `gcount` is less than 5, then previous read failed and failbit (eofbit and badbit potentionally too) is set, so you should handle that. Currently it either reads 5 characters or enters infinite loop.

Comment: It will never stop if I run `echo "123" | ./a.out`.